# Get N most common substrings from file

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a file that contains strings in the following format: `/path1/path2/path3`

I'd like to show the `N` most common `path2` substrings via unix command-line.

Could you give me some direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat <your_file> | cut -d "/" -f 3 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -n <N> | awk '{print $2}'
```

With:

- `cut -d "/" -f 3`: extract "path2" strings
- `sort | uniq -c | sort -rg`: count occurrences of each "path2" strings and sort
- `head -n <N> | awk '{print $2}'`: print first N